# how to disable the shopping cart url from search engine?

Tags: magento-1.7, google-search-console

Please help and guide me. Online store has shopping cart option in magento. search engine crawl the shopping cart page.but i want to disable the shopping cart url in google search. How to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a robots.txt file and place it in the root folder of your magento. Your robots.txt should look like this..

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /tag/
Disallow: /*.js$
Disallow: /*.css$
Disallow: /checkout/
Disallow: /app/
Disallow: /downloader/
Disallow: /js/
Disallow: /lib/
Disallow: /*.php$
Disallow: /pkginfo/
Disallow: /report/
Disallow: /var/
Disallow: /customer/
Disallow: /review/
Disallow: /test/
Disallow: /enable-cookies
Disallow: /index.php/admin/
Disallow: /catalog/
Disallow: /cms/index/noRoute/
Disallow: /checkout/cart
Disallow: /us/
Disallow: /catalogsearch/
Disallow: /*?
Allow: /?p=*
Sitemap: http://www.xxxxx.com/sitemap.xml
```

Copy the above code to the robots.txt. Then your search engine will not crawl the files that are listed in this file. You can check here that, I have added `/checkout/cart`. So that it will not crawl these links.